# Why doesn't this regular expression work in .NET (works in javascript and online tester)

Tags: c#, regex

I am creating a simple name check.  Very basic no numbers or a selection of special characters and it should pass.  It works in RegEx Planets tester for .net but not in actual .net

```
var name = "john";
var regex = new RegularExpressionAttribute(@"^(?!.*[0-9;!@#$%&*()=+{}|\:<>])");
regex.IsValid(name);
```

Also the expression works in the javascript validation side (unobtrusive version).

Please note this is for a DataAnnotation Regular Expression.  I setup this code above for clarity.  It seems that they work differently then `System.Text.RegularExpressionAttribute.Regex.IsMatch`.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?!.*[0-9;!@#$%&*()=+{}|\:<>])", ErrorMessage="Invalid Name"]
public string FirstName {get;set;}
```

I attempted to use the solution from the question referenced as duplicate.  But it seems like that will not work.  I tried various different version of the .*? (.*, .?, .*^ etc).  I think this question is different because it is a "negative" regular expression.  It is attempting to make sure nothing in the text matches.  Maybe this is throwing it off.

Comment: Are you actually using the Attribute as an attribute? If not, use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch` and it should match.

Comment: The code is actually failing with the dataannotation regular expression.  Oddly enough the System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch works.

Comment: Yes, differently. Just add `.*` at your pattern end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if there is still a way to give you credit for the answer I would.  Thank you this worked.

Comment: @Dan That is too basic, the point is that you need to *consume* the characters, not only to check if there is some pattern or not with lookarounds.

Comment: @Dan The linked question is really the same, except that its original expression wanted to match at the end of the string, while yours wants to match at the beginning. So if the solution to the linked question is to match *anything else* at the beginning, the solution to your problem is to match *anything else* at the end. So adding a `.*?` to your expression to match (literally) whatever at the end will make it work just fine.